# Can HDFS block size be changed during job run? Custom Split and Variant Size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am using hadoop 1.0.3. Can the input split/block be changed (increase/decrease) during run time based on some constraints. Is there a class to override to accomplish this mechanism like FileSplit/InputTextFormat? Can we have variant size blocks in HDFS depending on logical constraint in one job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not limited to TextInputFormat... Thats entirely configurable based on the data source you are reading. Most examples are line delimited plaintext, but that obviously doesn't work for XML, for example.

No, block boundaries can't change during runtime as your data should already be on disk, and ready to read.

But the InputSplit is dependent upon the InputFormat for the given job, which should remain consistent throughout a particular job, but the `Configuration` object in the code is basically a Hashmap which can be changed while running, sure

Comment: Thanks for answering. If we override the InputSplit and add our constraints, shouldn't this be technically changing the block size. For example I take 64mb block and trim it according to my constraints before passing it to the mapper. There should be different input blocks in mapper. If I can do this, can I also  request additional data/lines in addition to 64mb block to make a block ?

Comment: If the data source is splitable, mappers only work on one block each. I don't understand what you mean by trimming a block... You've already read a block, 64Mb, or whatever it's set at. The storage layer of Hadoop doesn't care about your downstream processing, so there is no preprocessing you can do when a file is placed to HDFS, and there's no step between requesting a file, getting the block information, and a mapper reading that block. And this hasn't changed even in hadoop 2.x or 3.x versions

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can I have the control of 64mb block and access it before sending it to the the mapper. Lets assume if the string Shujaat is 10 times in the block only than it should be sent to the mapper. By trimming I meant if the block has 11 occurences of shujaat than trim the data to fit only 10 occurences and send to the mapper. By increasing the size I meant if shujaat is in the block 9 times, increase the size so 10th shujaat can be in the block before sending it to the mapper. Makes sense?

Comment: No, doesn't make sense. We're assuming it's in there 10 times, so it's not 9 or 11. Plus, 64MB of data is really a lot. That string 10 times, even 10000 times isn't even close to 1MB. Even the latest versions of Hadoop have a default of 128MB... I don't understand your use case for needing this feature. What performance penalties are you seeing? What benchmarks have you run on your hardware to determine bottlenecks in resources?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to explain that if the certain constraint is not met in the  block, then the block is not useful to mapper for processing. So I wanted to make sure that the block is processable for the mapper. There is definitely a performance penalty in this approach due to preprocessing the block before the mapper. The question is that is it possible to check the constraint before sending it to the mapper? Thanks again

Comment: Preprocessing? The InputSplits determine what blocks are gathered by a mapper. And that already starts at the  block containing the file for the record. A blocksize is based on bytes, not strings, or characters, or line endings. You would need to have some reference to where a record started within a block to start reading from it or "trim to it". When the byte reader reaches a block boundary, the remainder of the current split is read and the rest of the next block is read until the map tasks are done. The block size would have to be changed before you placed the file to HDFS, not from a map

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change block size only for a particular run or application you can do by overriding "-D dfs.block.size=134217728" .It helps you to change block size for your application instead of changing overall block size in hdfs-site.xml.

-D dfs.block.size=134217728

Comment: You can also configure in your program by conf object 
Configuration conf = new Configuration() ;

conf.set( "dfs.block.size", 128*1024*1024) ;